# balls and buckets combinations with a minimum and maximum number of empty buckets

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, balls-in-bins

Given $K$ balls and $M$ buckets and the limits $L1$ and $L2$ where $0<L1<L2<M$. We distribute all balls in the buckets randomly so a bucket can end up with $0$ to $K$ balls.

> How do I calculate the number of combinations that have a number of empty buckets $E$ where $L1<E<L2$?

As I understand it without the restrictions the number of combinations are
$$
(K+M-1)!/(K!(M-1)!)
$$
but I do not know where to go from here.

If it makes it easier we can add the restriction $K<=M$ or even $K=M$

Comment: There appears to be a clash between "$K$ balls" and "...with $0$ to $M$ balls".

Comment: Thanks, my bad, I fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the bins are distinguishable.  In this case, if we know which $E$ buckets are empty, we can use [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) (the positive integer version).  So we sum over the possible $E$-subsets:
$$
\sum_{\substack{\mathcal{E} \subseteq \{1,\ldots,M\} \\ L1 < |\mathcal{E}| < L2}} \binom{K-1}{M-|\mathcal{E}|-1}
=
\sum_{E=L1+1}^{L2-1} \binom{M}{E} \binom{K-1}{M-E-1}.
$$

Comment: It works, thanks!